Instability during tests in the local environment with pnpm test
I hope you can help me, I am encountering errors when trying to run the account-data tests from this repository. https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples
My question is why, during the test execution, without any changes to the sources, it often fails as described below and sometimes it works? According to the configuration listed below,
I have an environment created and configured from scratch, so I shouldn’t have these strange behaviors during the tests.
Error message: /account-data/native# pnpm test

@ test /rocha/account-data/native pnpm ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 ./tests/test.ts

(node:2024) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead. (Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)

0 passing (1ms)

Possible bogus program name. Ensure the program name (Щdata_program) matches one of the following recognizable program names: [2024-08-04T10:09:43.397677636Z WARN solana_program_test] - account_data_program thread ‘tokio-runtime-worker’ panicked at /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/solana-program-test-1.18.0/src/lib.rs:716:17: Program file data not available for Щdata_program (11111111111111111111111111111112) note: run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display a backtrace

Environment configuration on the Docker image:
# Use the Solana base image
FROM solanalabs/solana:v1.18.17

# Install dependencies for Rust, Anchor, and Node.js
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    build-essential \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    nano

# Install Rust
RUN curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y
ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"

# Install Anchor CLI
RUN cargo install --git https://github.com/project-serum/anchor anchor-cli --locked

# Install Node.js
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_21.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs

# Install the latest compatible version of npm
RUN npm install -g npm@latest

# Copy project files
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

# Expose necessary ports
EXPOSE 8899 8900 8001 9901

# Start the Solana test validator and run tests
CMD ["sh", "-c", "solana-test-validator --reset --no-bpf-jit --limit-ledger-size --ledger /root/.config/solana/ledger --faucet-port 9901 & ts-node --loader ts-node/esm test.ts"]

After starting the Docker container and running in bash mode:
# inside the "account-data\native" folder
npm install -g pnpm
pnpm install
pnpm build
pnpm test

During various attempts to understand the problem, I also tried deleting the following files and folders:
file: Cargo.lock
folders: “node_modules”, “program\target” and “tests\fixtures”
